# How to create a wordpress plugin that will create and update custom post types from an external json feed

Tags: php, json, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created two custom post types - Seasons and Competitions what I would like to do is use data from an external api to make a wordpress plugin that will create and update these posts, I have made several attempts but so far failing to get this to work a sample of the api is:

```
 {"id":15,"startDate":"14-06-2014","endDate":"23-07-2015","competition":{"id":43,"name":"Champions League"},"sponsor":{"id":12,"name":"UEFA","description":"Uefa"}}``
```

and the code so far for the plugin:

```
function add_posts()
{

 $season_request    = 'https://somedomain/api/info';

$args = array(
'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( user . ':' . password)
)
);
$season_response = wp_remote_get( $season_request, $args );
 $season_data = json_decode($season_response['body']);

if(! $season_data)
return false;

$query = array(
  'meta_query' => array(

    array(
         'key' =>'season_id',
         'value' => $season_data->id
    )
),

'post_type' => 'seasons',
'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit'),
  'posts_per_page' => 1
 );

   $season = get_posts($query);
   $season_id = '';
   if($season)
   $season_id = $season[0] -> id;

   $season_post = array
  (
    'ID' => $season_id,
    'post_title' => $season_data -> startDate . endDate . 'test',
    'post_type' => 'seasons',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_status' => ($season) ? $season[0] -> post_status : 'publish'

   );

   $season_id = wp_insert_post($season_post);



  }
```

I'm relatively new to php(not to coding) so it may be something glaringly obvious that I can't see. I thought that this would be something that there would be some detailed documentation on but if there is it seems to be hidden from me pretty well. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: How do you create a wordpress plugin that will create and update custom post types from an external json feed?

Comment: Ok then, if you do not have a specific programming problem in this code snipped, but just want others to present some finished code for you - StackOverflow is not the right place.

Comment: I am not expecting others to present finished code to me - I was hoping someone would be able to tell me where I was going wrong and provide some suggestions for how to go about this the right way if you see what I have said under my code snippet I would have thought this was clear...I was under the impression that stackoverflow was somewhere you could come for guidance when you were learning for help from more experienced people - where do you suggested people learning new development skills go to for help if not stackoverflow?

Comment: I didn't want to sound rude. The thing is just that SO is more for questions like "In this code snipped, I tried this and that, but I encountered the following errors/I can't wrap my head around achieving this exact functionality" rather than "Ho do I code a plugin/library/application that does XY". If you have a specifc problem other than "there are only 10000 lines until it's complete, please help", that's absolutely ok. But it doesn't get clear from your wording, as it does sound more like one of the bad examples I provided. There are countless coding forums where this might fit better.

Comment: As @Connum stated, SO isn't a place made to ask for code or a full course/tutorial on a code.
If you have a precise problem or question, I invite you to edit your code in order to advance the problem you may encounter, so we can actually work together on fixing it and helping it to go further. Else, I'm sorry to announce that SO isn't the right place to answer this problem.

Comment: My problem is, I don't know why this piece of code is not working it is not throwing any errors, I'm not trying to ask for a full course/tutorial I just want someone to tell me what I am doing wrong because I can't see it myself. As far as I can tell this code should work and it doesn't - I hoped somebody could tell me why and offer me some suggestions or point out how I was going wrong. I didn't expect to get called up for trying to ask for help. If you can read the final paragraph of my original post I think it's clear I am asking for help not a full solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to call the external api was as follows:

```
$data_request    = 'https://yoururlforapihere/api/data';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';

$headers = array( 'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password" ) );
$data_response = wp_remote_get( $data_request, array( 'headers' =>$headers, 'sslverify' => false));
```

Once the data was coming in properly the rest became more straightforward.